# RelatedTarget attribute is absent for dynamically created Boostrap modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap modal built dynamically in an HTML which is generated on server-side as a response to an AJAX call. The problem is that I can't see `relatedTarget` attribute in the event. See the code below:

HTML:

```
<i id = '#open_modal_test' class="fa fa-envelope open-modal" aria-hidden="true"
    title = 'Test' data-placement="right"
    data-toggle = "tooltip" data-target="#test_form" data-head="{% Test %}" data-caller-type = ...></i>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('show.bs.modal', '#new_message_form', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $button = $(e.relatedTarget); // relatedTarget is undefined here
    var caller_type = $button.data('caller-type');
    alert(caller_type);
});

Both `#open_modal_test` element and `#new_message_form` are created dynamically.
```

The code for opening modal is as follows:

```
$(document).on('click', '.open-modal', function(e) {
        var $triggered_elem = $(this);
        var modal_id = $triggered_elem.data('target');
        $(modal_id).on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
            var head = $triggered_elem.data('head') // Extract info from data-* attributes
            var modal = $(this);
            modal.find('.modal-title').text(head);
        }).modal({backdrop:'static',keyboard:false});
    });
```

Does anyone know what's the cause of the issue ?

Comment: Where are you triggering the `.modal` call? Make sure you pass in a JQuery object as the 2nd param, e.g. `div.modal('toggle', $(// whatever //))`

Comment: See the updated question

Comment: What element exactly are you attempting to reference with `relatedTarget`?

Comment: element with id = `open_modal_test`. According to http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target)

Comment: Is that what the data-target attribute of `.open-modal` refers to?